# Hosted PowerShell cannot see Cmdlets in the same Assembly

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm trying to run PowerShell scripts from my C# code, that will use custom Cmdlets from the assembly that runs them. Here is the code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;

[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get,"Hello")]
public class GetHelloCommand:Cmdlet
{
    protected override void EndProcessing()
    {
        WriteObject("Hello",true);
    }
}

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PowerShell powerShell=PowerShell.Create();
        powerShell.AddCommand("Get-Hello");
        foreach(string str in powerShell.AddCommand("Out-String").Invoke<string>())
            Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

When I try to run it, I get a CommandNotFoundException.
Did I write my Cmdlet wrong? Is there something I need to do to register my Cmdlet in PowerShell or in the Runspace or something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way to do this with your current code snippet is like this:

```
using System; 
using System.Management.Automation; 

[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get,"Hello")] 
public class GetHelloCommand:Cmdlet 
{ 
    protected override void EndProcessing() 
    { 
        WriteObject("Hello",true); 
    } 
} 

class MainClass 
{ 
    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
        PowerShell powerShell=PowerShell.Create();

        // import commands from the current executing assembly
        powershell.AddCommand("Import-Module")
            .AddParameter("Assembly",
                  System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
        powershell.Invoke()
        powershell.Commands.Clear()

        powershell.AddCommand("Get-Hello"); 
        foreach(string str in powerShell.AddCommand("Out-String").Invoke<string>()) 
            Console.WriteLine(str); 
    } 
}
```

This assumes PowerShell v2.0 (you can check in your console with $psversiontable or by the copyright date which should be 2009.) If you're on win7, you are on v2.

Answer (score 5):

Yet another simple way is to register cmdlets in a runspace configuration, create a runspace with this configuration, and use that runspace.

```
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "Hello")]
public class GetHelloCommand : Cmdlet
{
    protected override void EndProcessing()
    {
        WriteObject("Hello", true);
    }
}

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create();
        var configuration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
        configuration.Cmdlets.Append(new CmdletConfigurationEntry[] { new CmdletConfigurationEntry("Get-Hello", typeof(GetHelloCommand), "") });
        powerShell.Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(configuration);
        powerShell.Runspace.Open();

        powerShell.AddCommand("Get-Hello");
        foreach (string str in powerShell.AddCommand("Out-String").Invoke<string>())
            Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

Just in case, with this approach cmdlet classes do not have to be public.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do this from inside the PowerShell? That is, to load a DLL using [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom, and then call a function that loads the Cmdlets to the current session of PowerShell?

Comment: I did not try that (just because did not have to). In PowerShell you can access the configuration of the default (more or less *current* but it depends) runspace as: `[System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace]::DefaultRunspace.RunspaceConfiguration`. Then try to call `.Cmdlets.Append(...)` on it. It would be nice if you try this and tell us the results.

Comment: I can't get it to work. It seems the Runspace won't load Cmdlets that way unless it's in the BeforeOpen state. Any way to load Cmdlets to an alreay open Runspace?

Answer (score 1):

You do need to register your cmdlet before you can use it in a Powershell session. You'll generally do that by way of a Powershell Snap-In. Here's a high-level overview of the process:

- Create custom cmdlets (you've already done this part)
- Create a Powershell Snap-in which contains and describes your cmdlets
- Install the new Snap-in on your system using `Installutil`
- Add the Snap-in to a specific Powershell session using `Add-PSSnapin`

There are a couple useful articles on MSDN that explain the process pretty thoroughly:

- [Developing with Windows PowerShell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303698.aspx)
- [How to Create a Windows PowerShell Snap-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136070%28VS.85%29.aspx)

There's also a 2-part series on ByteBlocks that discusses writing custom cmdlets. That series may be your best bet, since you seem to have done the equivalent of part 1 already. You may be able to just use part 2 as a quick reference and be good to go.

- [How to Write a Custom Cmdlet - Part 1](http://www.byteblocks.com/page/How-To-Write-Custom-Powershell-Cmdlet-Part-1.aspx)
- [How to Write a Custom Cmdlet - Part 2](http://www.byteblocks.com/page/How-To-Write-Custom-Powershell-Cmdlet-Part-2.aspx)

Comment: A SnapIn is the powershell v1 way of doing things and is discouraged these days as it requires administrative privileges to register them. He should be using powershell v2 modules.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question for what he is trying to do.

Comment: @manojlds It does answer the question, but is definitely not as up to date or elegant as x0n's answer.

Comment: @x0n I upvoted your answer since it's much more elegant and has the added benefit of being self-contained.