# How to add a PSCmdlet or PSSnapin to hosted Powershell runtime without installing the snapin

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

My scenario is as follows.

- I am uploading my dll through web UI.
- I am hosting a PowerShell runspace in an ASP.NET application.
- I The DLL contains the PSCmdlet and would like to make use of it.
- The PSCmdlet only needs to be accessible within the hosted runspace and does not need to be 
  used in any external scenario.
- The application does not have access to the windows registry as it runs with limited privileges, so I cannot install the PsSnapin.

Is it possible for me to use the commandlet without going through the installation process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your use case is straightforward then it is possible. Please see these question: [Hosted PowerShell cannot see Cmdlets in the same Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7560728/323582). Several answers there provide different ways, choose one that works better or you like more.

Answer (score 0):

If you use PowerShell V2 you can use an unregistered snapin as a binary module.

```
Import-Module ‹path-to-dll›
```

add a `-passthru` to get the `PSModuleInfo` reference which describes the module.