# How do I find ActiveSync attributes from Exchange with C#?

Tags: .net, exchange-server, activesync

I'm trying to find some ActiveSync attributes from Exchange. I found a good [article](http://exchangepedia.com/2008/06/exchange-server-2007-listing-exchange-activesync-users-and-device-information.html) that shows a PowerShell cmdlet for finding this information. But I'm trying to find where this information is actually stored. I looked at my user objects in [ADSI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa772170%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) edit to see if any of the properties would be these values, but this does not seem to be the case.
**How do I find this information with C#?**

Comment: You could use the powershell & the cmdlet from C#, in process. Something similar to what can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560728/hosted-powershell-cannot-see-cmdlets-in-the-same-assembly

Comment: yes - that is possible... see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

To get ActiveSync attributes for a specific ActiveDirectory Object (i.e. user) you can use 
[CASMailbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.data.directory.management.casmailbox_members%28v=EXCHG.140%29.aspx) class.

It has a constructor taking an ADObject and then gives you several properties like [`HasActiveSyncDevicePartnership`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.data.directory.management.casmailbox.hasactivesyncdevicepartnership%28v=EXCHG.140%29.aspx) - you can even change these (provided you have needed permissions that is).

EDIT - as per comments:

The `CASMailbox` class has all you ask.
For example `ActiveSyncMailboxPolicy` which is an `ADObjectId` which in turn can be queried for several properties...
Another example `ActiveSyncAllowedDeviceIDs` which is a `MultiValuedProperty` which you can query for DeviceIDs etc.

This way of accessing the properties might not be nice but it certainly gives you all information... if you want some rather nice source code (which in this case works with PS) see http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp/Web/dotpanel/dotPanel/Providers/HostedSolution/Exchange2007.cs.htm

Comment: While this class does give me the 'HasActiveSyncDevicePartnership' property, it does not look to expose any of the actual ActiveSync attributes such as DeviceType, DeviceID, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Get-CASMailbox** will give you basic information such as **HasActiveSyncDevicePartnerShip**. These properties are stored in active directory, you can view them with adsiedit right under the person account.

If you want more properties like **DeviceFriendlyName, LastSuccessSync, DeviceImei**, they have to be retrieved from the mailbox itself using the PS Cmdlet Get-MobileDeviceStatistics.

There are several methods to use PS CmdLets inside C# code, for exchange you will probably want to use PS Remoting : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9627716/1984242